# Display body text from custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using [PODS](http://pods.io/) to create custom post types. I want to display these post types in my custom template. I've been able to display the title, image, but haven't found a way to display body content yet. I have tried `get_the_content( $id )` without luck. Any ideas?

```
<?php
      $pod = pods( 'selectoffers' );
      $related = $pod->field( 'select' );
     if ( ! empty( $related ) ) {
        foreach ( $related as $rel ) {
          $id = $rel[ 'ID' ];?>
           <div class="col-lg-4">
              <div class="round-img img-circle" style="background-image:url('<?php echo pods_image_url(get_post_meta( $id, 'bilde', true ), $size = 'full'); ?>');"></div>
                 <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $id ); ?></h2>
                   <p> [[THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD THE BODY]] </p>
                   <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php $lenke = get_post_meta( $id, 'lenke', true );
                      echo esc_url( get_permalink( array_shift($lenke) ) ); ?>" role="button">Les mer &raquo;</a></p>
              </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <?php
        } //end of foreach
     } //endif ! empty ( $related )
?>
```

Comment: the_content() is the function you want, but why are you not using the loop?

Comment: If've tried both the_content() and the_content($id), but none of them returns anything. What do you mean by not using the loop?

Comment: if you google wp loop you should find loads of detail on the loop which is basically a set of functions to create templates. the_content only works within the loop (you'll want this function working for a few reasons)

Comment: The main reason is because I'm using the Pods plugin to create custom settings where I select which posts to be shown. Maybe I could still use the loop, but just got it working this way (check answer).

Comment: yep that will work. But the loop should work for any post type, so check it out at some stage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it working using the following code:

```
$content_post = get_post($id);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```